# Replace pieces of groovy code inside string by code execution result with java like in SoapUI

Tags: java, groovy

I have xml data in config file I want to post and I need some dynamic part in this xml, like UUID, current date...

In SoapUI I can use Groovy script directly inside the xml like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <date>${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX\).format(new Date())}</date>
        <uddi>${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}</uddi>
    <Body>
<Envelope>
```

And I get this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <date>2016-04-07T15:29:43.729+02:00</date>
        <uddi>5f8020d3-1fe0-4755-8056-cdef536c98b9</uddi>
    <Body>
<Envelope>
```

I tryed with this code and it work well for UUID but not for SimpleDateFormat.

```
String sExecUUID = "\"UUID\" -> ${java.util.UUID.randomUUID()} !!!"; // OK : "UUID" -> 5f8020d3-1fe0-4755-8056-cdef536c98b9 !!!
String sExecDate = "\"Date\" -> ${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX\").format(new Date())} !!!"; // KO

//String sExec = sExecUUID;
String sExec = sExecDate;
sExec = sExec.replace("\\","\\\\"); // Replace \ --> \\
sExec = sExec.replace("\n","\\n");  // Replace \n --> \\n
sExec = sExec.replace("\r","\\r");  // Replace \n --> \\n
sExec = sExec.replace("\"","\\\""); // Replace " --> \"
sExec = "println \""+sExec+"\"";

// call groovy expressions from Java code
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
Object value = shell.evaluate(sExec);
System.out.println(value);
```

The exception for the date is:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1,
>   column 55.    ew java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-

I know it's due to my `\"` in SimpleDateFormat instead of `"` but I have to escape `"` to use `println`.

How can I have this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy has an interface called `TemplateEngine` with differents implementations like the `SimpleTemplateEngine`.

This template is what you need : they use a text with placeholders (${..} or the jsp syntax <%..%>). The placeholder can contain any groovy code.

From the official documentation :

```
def binding = [
     firstname : "Grace",
     lastname  : "Hopper",
     accepted  : true,
     title     : 'Groovy for COBOL programmers'
 ]
 def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
 def text = '''\
 Dear <%= firstname %> $lastname,

 We <% if (accepted) print 'are pleased' else print 'regret' %> \
 to inform you that your paper entitled
 '$title' was ${ accepted ? 'accepted' : 'rejected' }.

 The conference committee.
 '''
 def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
 println template.toString()
```

see [SimpleTemplateEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html)